# How to Apply Lambda Function to get a negative Week Number?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new column from my dataframe which will return the following:

If the year of column Date Created is 2019, then it will return the weeknumber. Otherwise, it should reflect the [weeknumber of DateCreated - 52] (This is to return a negative weeknumber from the weeknumbers of 2019)

This is what i tried so far

```
sy2019['Week Number'] = sy2019.apply(lambda x: x['Date Created'].dt.strftime('%U') 
                                     if x['Date Created'].dt.year == 2019
                                     else x['Date Created'].dt.strftime('%U') - 52
                                    )
```

I get this error: KeyError: ('Date Created', 'occurred at index ID')

I am wondering where I went wrong here and how I can correct this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have to specify the `axis` value in the apply function and a small change to the code:

```
sy2019['Week Number'] = sy2019.apply(lambda x: x['Date Created'].week 
                                 if x['Date Created'].year == 2019
                                 else x['Date Created'].week - 52, axis=1
                                )
```